# Does one need to call pack()/layout() in an SWT composite constructor?

Tags: java, swt

Do I need to call `pack()` and/or `layout()` in the constructor of my widget?

(I followd the instruction on [Wrapping an SWT Widget](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm))

```
public class MyWidget extends Composite
{
    public MyWidget(Composite parent, int style)
    {
        super(parent, style);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Label lblFoo = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        lblFoo.setText("Don't panic");

        Button btnNewButton = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton.setText("OK");

        pack();   // ?
        layout(); // ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the short answer - NO. You don't have to do that in a constructor.

As  Marko Topolnik mentioned in the comments, these methods will be executed when the widget is just about to be shown.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, I would like to understand the reasons.

Comment: The equivalent of pack and layout is called on your widget anyway when  it is about to be shown.

Comment: I was looking for the place which calls `pack()`/`layout()` but found nothing and suspect `shell.open()` to do this but have no proof, do you know where it is done?